# Proper way of encoding a java script string

Tags: javascript

I have used escape function of java script to encode a java script string. But the result appears to be weird one which consists of the following characters:

```
%3CBitte%20w%E4hlen%3E
```

…for the string:

```
Bitte wählen
```

…which is a German sentence. I need the output as `Bitte wählen`.

The following code may help you understand clearly

```
var temp = escape(String(<Bitte wählen>));
```

Comment: That last code sample is not JavaScript.

Comment: escape is not for encoding. It's to escape special URL characters, as you could easily see by reading the docs. What exactly you want to encode? Your sample string is the same before and after encoding so it makes no sense.

Comment: What's your question? You're encoding the string but you seem to be surprised it contains "weird" characters - what are you expecting `escape` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not really clear what you mean.

To escape any character in JavaScript, [read up on JavaScript character escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes), or just use [mothereff.in/js-escapes](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1Bitte%20w%C3%A4hlen). That page tells you that in JavaScript, `'Bitte wählen'` can be written as `'Bitte w\xe4hlen'` or even `'\x42\x69\x74\x74\x65\x20\x77\xe4\x68\x6c\x65\x6e'`.

Comment: I need to escape special characters in the given string

Comment: @Sindhe Using JavaScript? (I’m asking because the last code sample in your post is not JavaScript.) Have a look at the source of the tool that I linked to: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/mothereff.in/blob/master/js-escapes/eff.js

Answer (score 0):

```
function URLDecode (encodedString) {
  var output = encodedString;
  var binVal, thisString;
  var myregexp = /(%[^%]{2})/;
  while ((match = myregexp.exec(output)) != null
             && match.length > 1
             && match[1] != '') {
    binVal = parseInt(match[1].substr(1),16);
    thisString = String.fromCharCode(binVal);
    output = output.replace(match[1], thisString);
  }
  return output;
}


alert(URLDecode("%3CBitte%20w%E4hlen%3E"));​ // <Bitte wählen>
```

(Code taken from [here](http://cass-hacks.com/articles/code/js_url_encode_decode/))

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/nnRpn/